# Generate SQLite script

Tags: database, scripting, sqlite

I am using Enterprise Architect to model databases. Now, I want to generate some tables for SQLite database, but they [do not](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) implement the full SQL92.

My problem is the `ALTER TABLE Node ADD CONSTRAINT FK_name FOREIGN KEY (field) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME (ID)`

Is there any good script/model to generate SQLite scripts?

Pedro

**EDIT**

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE MonitoredData ( 
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
NODE INTEGER,
MINUTE INTEGER,
HOUR INTEGER,
DAY INTEGER,
MONTH INTEGER,
YEAR INTEGER,
SPAN INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE Node ( 
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
MEMORY_USAGE INTEGER,
CPU_USAGE INTEGER,
NETWORK_USAGE INTEGER,
DISK_USAGE INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES MonitoredData(NODE)
);
CREATE TABLE MemoryUsage ( 
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
SIZE INTEGER,
RESIDENT INTEGER,
SHARE INTEGER,
TEXT INTEGER,
DATA INTEGER,
VIRTUALSIZE INTEGER,
RSS INTEGER,
RSSLIM TEXT,
MEM_TOTAL INTEGER,
MEM_USED INTEGER,
MEM_FREE INTEGER,
MEM_BUFFERS INTEGER,
MEM_CACHED INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Node(MEMORY_USAGE)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite requires that foreign key constraints be created at the same time as the table. From the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics):

```sql
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```

You also need to enable foreign key enforcement on a *per-connection* basis (for historical reasons):

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Comment: thanks... but, can you see the problem with my queries which I added in a edit?

Comment: i was missing a comma... shame on me x)